# AJAX request SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am making an AJAX GET request using jQuery. I get a response in JSON format when I use JSONP as datatype, but I also always get this error:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: show us your code. this is a syntax error. the context doesn't matter.

Comment: Care to share some code ? I guess you're missing a ; before statement :)

Comment: its parsing error in my response

Comment: {"expand":"renderedFields,names,......... i got sysntax error at colon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment (which you should add in your question by editing it BTW), your problem comes from here :

```
{"expand":"renderedFields,names...
```

Your JSON is not valid: add `"` just after `renderedFields` and around `names`. Also, `names` is a property name, meaning it needs a value:

```
{
    "expand":"renderedFields",
    "names":"someValue",
    //... 
}
```

Comment: Dont post all that in comments. Edit your question and paste that there. This is what you should have done from the beginning.

Comment: Why did you delete your comment ?